# DB2 delete and with statement

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete

The following nested DB2 SQL query is not working. This has nested DELETE and WITH statements

```
delete from ADDRESS 
where 
    ADDRESS_ID in (with     addr (ADDRESS_ID) as (select a.ADDRESS_ID from ADDRESS a where a.MEMBER_ID between 50000000 and 999999999 and a.STATUS='T' and a.LASTCREATE < (current timestamp - 42 days)), 
                addrorder (ADDRESS_ID) as ( select ad.ADDRESS_ID from ADDR ad LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS o on o.ADDRESS_ID = ad.ADDRESS_ID where o.ADDRESS_ID is null), 
                addordi (ADDRESS_ID) as ( select ao.ADDRESS_ID from ADDRORDER ao LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS oi on oi.ADDRESS_ID=ao.ADDRESS_ID where oi.ADDRESS_ID is null), 
                addordia (ADDRESS_ID) as ( select aoi.ADDRESS_ID from ADDORDI aoi LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS oi ON oi.ALLOCADDRESS_ID=aoi.ADDRESS_ID where oi.ALLOCADDRESS_ID is null)
                select distinct aoia.ADDRESS_ID from ADDORDIA aoia LEFT OUTER JOIN HD_MEMBER_SUBSCR ms ON ms.ADDRESS_ID=aoia.ADDRESS_ID where ms.ADDRESS_ID is null fetch first 800000 rows only for read only with ur);
```

Comment: "Not working" _how_?  What error are you getting?  And what version/platform for DB2 (as some don't support this syntax at all.

Answer (score 0):

Going with what may be the simplest solution: your query doesn't need any CTEs.  Generally speaking, use a CTE when

1. You're trying to abstract away some set of joins/operations (ie, usually created as a view)
2. You plan on referencing the result more than once

(There's a related one for naming aggregate result sets, but that can be done with a joined subquery)

For simple conditions, don't bother.  The following should run in almost every version of DB2 (and, barring `FETCH FIRST`, almost every RDBMS):

```
DELETE FROM Address 
WHERE member_id >= 50000000 
      AND member_id < 1000000000
      AND status = 'T'
      AND lastCreate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 42 DAYS
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                      FROM Orders
                      WHERE Orders.address_id = Address.address_id)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                      FROM OrderItems
                      WHERE OrderItems.addressId = Address.address_id
                            OR OrderIterms.allocAddress_id = Address.address_id)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                      FROM HD_Member_Subscr
                      WHERE HD_Member_Subscr.address_id = Address.address_id)
FETCH FIRST 800000 ROWS ONLY
WITH UR
```

(actually, I wonder if the `FOR READ ONLY` was part of the problem.  Note that without an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the rows will be random - although likely by `address_id` anyways).

Note that I've swapped out `BETWEEN` for an exclusive range (I personally believe `BETWEEN` should be deprecated, and advocate explicitly defined ranges for even integer ranges, for consistency reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the above query. But, using "NOT EXISTS" in the query degrades the performance. Any other solution?

Comment: Well, you can do like @bhamby suggests, unless you can point us to your version/platform of DB2 that might support something better.  How do you know this degrades performance, if your first query wasn't running anyways?  Post explain plans if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Clockwork-Muse that you don't really need CTEs here, and I don't think DB2 supports CTEs with a `DELETE` statement, anyway (at least on LUW).

Since you say that performance is bad with the `NOT EXISTS` clause, you could try this alternative with `LEFT JOIN`s, but I'm not sure it will be much better. The below logic assumes that the address fields in the tables other than the address fields are defined with `NOT NULL`, if this isn't the case

If you're really deleting enough entries to require you to do it eight hundred thousand entries at a time, then you probably have a lot of data, and it's going to be fairly slow no matter how you handle it.

Also, why do you have `WITH UR`? Do you really want to delete uncommitted rows?

```
DELETE FROM Address 
WHERE member_id >= 50000000 
  AND member_id < 1000000000
  AND status = 'T'
  AND lastCreate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 42 DAYS

  AND address_id IN (
    SELECT address_id FROM (
        SELECT
             A.address_ID
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RN
        FROM Address     A
        LEFT JOIN Orders O
          ON O.address_id = A.address_id
        LEFT JOIN OrderItems OI
          ON OI.addressId = A.address_id
        LEFT JOIN OrderItems OI2
          ON OI2.allocAddress_id = A.address_id
        LEFT JOIN HD_Member_Subscr H
          ON H.address_id= A.address_id
        WHERE O.addressId         IS NULL
          AND OI.addressId        IS NULL
          AND OI2.allocAddress_id IS NULL
          AND H.address_id        IS NULL
    ) T1
    WHERE RN <= 800000
  )
```

Comment: Throws the following error  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);.address_id IS NULL
;<space>, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: @user3175639: what platform are you on? Mainframe? Linux/Unix/Windows? iSeries?

Comment: Actually, assuming you're on LUW, the issue is that a `DELETE` doesn't support using a `FETCH FIRST`. Kinda slipped my mind that that wouldn't work. If you *really* need a limit, you can use the proposed option in my latest edit.